# WPF messagebox UCEERR_RENDERTHREADFAILURE

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In my wpf I have a stackPanel that is normally not visible.
 When the stack panel is visible and a messageBox is displayed, after the messageBox is cleared the stack panel visibility is set to false. 
If you attempt to set the visibility of that stack panel to true again, the variable gets set but nothing is displayed, shortly after this error message displays.
[image]

If I remove the messageBox the code runs fine and displays properly. Problems only occur when a message box displays, even if the messageBox only contains a string and nothing else.
Is there a proper way to clear a messageBox from memory in wpf?